# Convert key-value pairs into columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Here's code snippet which combines all columns in a given table.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp1') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp1

create table #temp1(id float null, value nvarchar(100) null)
insert into #temp1 values(1, 'xyz')
insert into #temp1 values(2, 'pqr')
insert into #temp1 values(null, 'lmn')

select * from #temp1

id                     value
---------------------- ------------
1                      xyz
2                      pqr
NULL                   lmn

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SELECT @sql = ISNULL(@sql + ')' + '+''|''+ ','') + '''' + c.name + '=''+' + 'convert(nvarchar(max), COALESCE(' + c.name + ', '''')'
FROM tempdb.sys.all_columns c 
WHERE Object_ID = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp1')
SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @sql + ')+' + ''''' FROM #temp1'
EXEC( @sql)
```

returns result correctly.

```
--------------------------------
id=1|value=xyz
id=2|value=pqr
id=0|value=lmn
```

For another table, result look good as well.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp2') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp2

create table #temp2(city nvarchar(100) null, temp1 float null, temp2 float null)
insert into #temp2(city, temp1, temp2) values('new york', 20, 12)
insert into #temp2(city, temp1, temp2) values('chicago', 15, 17)
insert into #temp2(city, temp1, temp2) values('portland', null, 5)

select * from #temp2

city     temp1  temp2
---------------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
new york 20   12
chicago  15   17
portland NULL 5
```

result

```
city=new york|temp1=20|temp2=12
city=chicago|temp1=15|temp2=17
city=portland|temp1=0|temp2=5
```

Now, What I want to do is exactly opposite, for given key-value pairs return the rows in column & value format.

e.g. for

```
city=chicago|temp1=15|temp2=17
city=portland|temp1=0|temp2=5

city     temp1 temp2
--------------------
chicago  15    17
portland NULL  5
```

Comment: How about simply store it as XML/JSON format and use native support for this data types?

Comment: json will do. Do you have any example which dump columns into json structure and converts them back to table structure.

Comment: **[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4c8a429afeb0074bfc56c4ffd340e064)**

Comment: Thanks. But I am using Sql server 2012. JSON is not supported there.

Comment: Plus, I don't want to pass column names when parsing. Script must read key value pairs and interpret all keys as columns.

Comment: Why down voting?

Comment: Please do not imply that I downvote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by some thing similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE #DYNAMIC (VAL VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #DYNAMIC 
VALUES('ID=1|VALUE=XYZ'),('ID=2|VALUE=PQR'),('ID=0|VALUE=LMN')

DECLARE @SQL_BUILD VARCHAR(MAX)='';
SELECT @SQL_BUILD = @SQL_BUILD + VAL FROM (
SELECT  'SELECT ' +REPLACE(VAL,'|','&COMMA&'  )+ ', UNION ALL ' VAL FROM #DYNAMIC
)A

SELECT @SQL_BUILD = REPLACE(@SQL_BUILD,'=','=''');
SELECT @SQL_BUILD = REPLACE(@SQL_BUILD,',','''');
SELECT @SQL_BUILD =REPLACE(@SQL_BUILD,'&COMMA&',''',');
SELECT @SQL_BUILD = SUBSTRING(@SQL_BUILD,1,LEN(@SQL_BUILD)-10)

EXEC(@SQL_BUILD)
```

Result:

```
ID  VALUE
---------
1   XYZ
2   PQR
0   LMN
```